Error with pg in Jest-ts testing : Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting: ● TCPWRAP
I have been facing the problem where my Jest test is not ending gracefully. (I prefer not to use --force-exit).
this is my jest code. FYI the tests passes. This is an integration testing.
import request from 'supertest';
import { registerCoreMiddleWare } from '../../boot/setup';
import { App } from 'supertest/types';
import pool from '../../boot/database/db_connect';

let app: App;

beforeAll(async () => {
  app = registerCoreMiddleWare();
  // Create tables if they do not exist
  await pool.query(`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
      email VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
      username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      creation_date DATE NOT NULL
    );
  `);

  await pool.query(`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addresses (
      email VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES users(email),
      country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      city VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      street VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    );
  `);
});



describe('User Registration and Login Integration Tests', () => {
  const testUser = {
    email: 'testuser@example.com',
    username: 'testuser',
    password: 'testpassword',
    country: 'TestCountry',
    city: 'TestCity',
    street: 'TestStreet',
    creation_date: new Date(),
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await pool.query('DELETE FROM addresses;');
    await pool.query('DELETE FROM users;');
  });
  afterEach(async () => {
    await pool.query('DELETE FROM addresses;');
    await pool.query('DELETE FROM users;');
  });

  describe('User Registration', () => {
    it('should register a new user', async () => {
      const response = await request(app)
        .post('/users/register')
        .send(testUser)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200);

      expect(response.body.message).toBe('User created');
    });

    it('should not register an existing user', async () => {
      await request(app)
        .post('/users/register')
        .send(testUser)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200);

      const response = await request(app)
        .post('/users/register')
        .send(testUser)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(409);

      expect(response.body.message).toBe('User already has an account');
    });

    it('should not register a user with missing parameters', async () => {
      const response = await request(app)
        .post('/users/register')
        .send({})
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(400);

      expect(response.body.message).toBe('Missing parameters');
    });
  });

  describe('User Login', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await request(app)
        .post('/users/register')
        .send(testUser)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200);
    });

    it('should login an existing user', async () => {
      const response = await request(app)
        .post('/users/login')
        .send({
          email: testUser.email,
          password: testUser.password,
        })
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200);

      expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('token');
      expect(response.body.username).toBe(testUser.username);
    });

    it('should not login with incorrect credentials', async () => {
      const response = await request(app)
        .post('/users/login')
        .send({
          email: testUser.email,
          password: 'wrongpassword',
        })
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(404);

      expect(response.body.message).toBe('Incorrect email/password');
    });

    it('should not login with missing parameters', async () => {
      const response = await request(app)
        .post('/users/login')
        .send({})
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(400);

      expect(response.body.message).toBe('Missing parameters');
    });
  });
});


// at the end of the test, close the pool
afterAll(async () => {

  pool.end();

});

this is my DB connection
import pg from 'pg';
import logger from '../../middleware/winston';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const isTestEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test';

let db_config: pg.PoolConfig;
if (isTestEnv && process.env.TEST_DB_URI) {
  db_config = {
    connectionString: process.env.TEST_DB_URI,
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  };
} else {
  db_config = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: 5432,
    max: 10,
  };
}

let db_connection: pg.Pool;

function startConnection(): void {
  pg.types.setTypeParser(1082, (stringValue: string): string => {
    return stringValue;

  });

  db_connection = new pg.Pool(db_config);

  db_connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      logger.error('PostgreSQL Connection Failed', { error: err.message, stack: err.stack });
      throw err;
    } else {
      logger.info('PostgreSQL Connected');
    }
  });

  db_connection.on('error', (err) => {
    logger.error('Unexpected error on idle client', { error: err.message, stack: err.stack });
    startConnection();
  });
}

export const closeConnection = async (): Promise<void> => {
  if (db_connection) {
    try {
      await db_connection.end();
      logger.info('PostgreSQL Connection Closed');
    } catch (err) {
      logger.error('Error closing PostgreSQL connection', { error: err.message, stack: err.stack });
      throw err;
    } finally {
      db_connection = null;
    }
  }
};

startConnection();

export default db_connection;


I am going crazy. This is the error for the openhandle i keep on getting
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  TCPWRAP

      35 |   db_connection = new pg.Pool(db_config);
      36 |
    > 37 |   db_connection.connect((err) => {
         |                 ^
      38 |     if (err) {
      39 |       logger.error('PostgreSQL Connection Failed', { error: err.message, stack: err.stack });
      40 |     } else {

      at Connection.connect (node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:44:17)
      at Client._connect (node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:113:11)
      at Client.connect (node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:162:12)
      at BoundPool.newClient (node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:237:12)
      at BoundPool.connect (node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:212:10)
      at connect (src/boot/database/db_connect.ts:37:17)
      at Object.startConnection (src/boot/database/db_connect.ts:65:1)
      at Object.require (src/controllers/movies.controller.ts:1:1)
      at Object.require (src/routes/movies.routes.ts:2:1)
      at Object.require (src/boot/setup.ts:12:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/user/integration.spec.ts:2:1)

PS D:\Software_Integration\movies-backend-pipeline> 

I tried using a function to close the pool from the db_connect module. I assumed there might be an error with the way the afterAll func is called, but even using done() (as I saw in a diff post) doesnt fix this. wierd thing is using an await before pool.end fails my test suite as well with timeout error.
● Test suite failed to run

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
    Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

      143 |
      144 | // at the end of the test, close the pool
    > 145 | afterAll(async () => {
          | ^
      146 |
      147 |   await pool.end();
      148 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/user/integration.spec.ts:145:1)


